# Cannot merge or slide accidentally opened windows

Tags: viewlayers

I realise that you should be able to grab and slide view layers to close them. I have done this successfully in the past. However, as a NOOB, I managed to get into a complete mess with shader windows that, when I tried to slide away, just opened window after window. I do realise it will be because I got the grab and slide wrong. However, they are not now in any position to slide over each other and I also cannot merge them for similar reasons. They are lying one on top of the other and grab does not achieve anything. Is there another way of closing these?

Comment: Hello, if you are using one of the latest versions, you can right click on the separating line between two editor windows and choose "join areas" then slide the cursor to close one of them. You can also start fresh with a new workspace by clicking on the "+" on top of the main window

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find a way with a lot of trial and error. The grab and slide worked eventually after selecting different combinations of windows. Cheers